# Flask-Restplus / route

Tags: python, flask-restplus

I'm trying to use Flask-Restplus to make an api and document it with swagger.

This is what I have so far and it works fine except I do not know how to add a root route.

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, apidoc

app = Flask('__name__')
blueprint = Blueprint('v1', __name__, url_prefix='/rest/v1')
api = Api(blueprint, ui=False, version='1.0')

@blueprint.route('/apidoc/', endpoint='apidoc')
def swagger_ui():
   return apidoc.ui_for(api)

@blueprint.route('/', endpoint='rootres')
  def root():
     return ''

app.register_blueprint(blueprint)


ns = api.namespace('test', description='desc')

@ns.route('/', endpoint='rootresource')
class RootResource(Resource)
   def get(self):
       ...
```

while /rest/v1/test works fine, /rest/v1 gives me Page not found.

if I modify like this:

```
@blueprint.route('/aaa', endpoint='rootres')
   def root():
      return ''
```

then /rest/v1/aaa works.

Question: how can I make @blueprint.route('/') work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote `ui=False` you disabled the `/rest/v1/` path.

In the next coming release (the 0.8.1 for the end of this week), you should be able to write:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

app = Flask('__name__')
blueprint = Blueprint('v1', __name__, url_prefix='/rest/v1')
api = Api(blueprint, doc='/apidoc/', version='1.0')

@blueprint.route('/', endpoint='rootres')
def root():
    return ''

ns = api.namespace('test', description='desc')

@ns.route('/', endpoint='rootresource')
class RootResource(Resource)
    def get(self):
        ...

app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

No need anymore to register a specific view for the documentation

For the `blueprint.route('/'), I think this is fixed by 0.8.1 too.

Note: register the blueprint later, after namespaces import/declaration.

Answer (score 9):

I found very similar problem. I wanted make '/' route with custom page, and swagger doc on different path.

**My first attempt (Not working)**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(
    app= app,
    version='1.0',
    description='TEST API',
    doc='/docs/',
)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello on my page"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Page `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` return 404 error

**Working example**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello on my page"

api = Api(
    app= app,
    version='1.0',
    description='TEST API',
    doc='/docs/',
    default='mapi',
    default_label='Super API'
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Tested on:

- Python 3.6.1
- Flask (0.12.1)
- flask-restplus (0.10.1)

Comment: You're awesome. Your answer made my day. thank you! ^_^