# Flask route at / returns 404 when used with Flask-Restplus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have a Flask app which has a Flask-RestPlus API as well as a "/" route. When I try to access "/" however, I get a 404. If I remove the Flask-RestPlus extension, the route works. How do I make both parts work together?

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, doc="/doc/")  # Removing this makes / work

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "foobar"
```

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/247

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask-Restplus / route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477878/flask-restplus-route)

Comment: Maybe we should close the other one as a duplicate. I think my question is way clearer / the MCVE is way shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/247) in Flask-RestPlus. As described in [this comment](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/247#issuecomment-402048647) on that issue, changing the order of the `route` and `Api` solves the issue.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "foobar"

api = Api(app, doc="/doc/")
```

Answer (score 0):

`flask-restplus` defines a different way of assigning routes according to their docs:

```py
@api.route('/')
class Home(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

Notice that the `api` variable is used instead of the `app`. Moreover, a class is used although I am not 100% sure it is required.

Comment: But I don't want the main page to contain the API. I want the main page to use `render_template` (or, to keep it simple and minimal here - "foobar")

Comment: I see. I think you should mention it in your question. Anyway, have you tested the following? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780748/695377